# Make visual studio solution files(sln) always executed as administrator

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015

I have solutions in Visual Studio which are configured to use IIS or to update SQL server database. If the solution is not run as administrator the project which is configured with IIS doesn't loads, because I don't have permissions. So my workaround is to run the Visual Studio 2013/2015 always as administrator(even I'm in the admin account) and open the project from there. In this case everything is working.

The visual studio solution files doesn't have the possibility to be ran as administrator **(also the advanced option in the properties of the shortcut has run as administrator not enabled and not editable)**. How I can achieve that, I search in the web that I can add registry, but I try one or two of the suggestions and nothing worked.

**How I can achieve to open solution files always as administrator on both vs 2013/2015.**

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.Launcher.sln\Shell\runas\Command]
>   @="\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe\" \"%1\""

This is what I had tried, without success.

Comment: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Side-By-Side-Office-Changing-Look-of-Folders-Cycling-Windows#c634698337025102994

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Locate the `devenv.exe` executable on your hard drive.  You can usually find it in the following places:

**Visual Studio 2013**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

**Visual Studio 2015**
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

**Visual Studio 2017** 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\<SKU_TYPE>\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`

Right click on the `devenv.exe` executable in Windows Explorer and select "Troubleshoot compatibility" and then select "Troubleshoot program."  From the next screen select "The program requires additional permissions" and then complete the wizard.

This will change your settings so that any time you try to run Visual Studio you will be running elevated.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked. Only one thing for Visual Studio 2013 the correct path is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe, not 13. You can edit that if you want.

Comment: I've had an issue where I couldn't hit my breakpoint when running VS2015 on Win10. After doing this, it started working again. Not saying it makes sense; but it worked. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: +1 for printing out the possible location(s) of `devenv.exe`

Comment: This doesn't work any longer and I just send MS a nasty gram in no uncertain terms about it.

Followed all the steps, all the way through the wizard and STILL Windows 10 won't respect the new settings.

What do you need from me for clarification?

Thanks!

Comment: @user1585204, not sure what's wrong.  I have still used this method on Windows 10 without problems.  Do you by chance have multiple SKUs/versions of Visual Studio installed?

Answer (score 2):

In Windows 10 do the following steps:
 - Download and install the ['Everything'](https://www.voidtools.com/) application that locates files and folders by name instantly.
 - Find the 'devenv.exe' and locate it.

[image: Everything]

- Right-click on 'devenv.exe' and select "Troubleshoot compatibility".
  Then select "Troubleshoot program".
  Then check "The program requires additional permissions".
  Then test the setting and save setting in next page.

[image: Troubleshoot compatibility]

[image: Troubleshoot program]

[image: The program requires additional permissions]

[image: Run As admin]

Answer (score 1):

StackExchange has already answered this and is more comprehensive, covering Windows 7, 8, 10 as well as modifying jump lists. In general most people won't want to **always** run as admin, so permanently modifying the devenv.exe doesn't seem like a good *general* solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9654833/how-to-run-visual-studio-as-administrator-by-default

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the answers in yours; answers should be as self-contained as possible. Also note that checking the "run as administrator" box is reversible, and doesn't actually change the executable file.

Comment: The relevant part of the top voted answer is several paragraphs long, and covers the steps for Windows 7, 8, and 10. The steps are different for 7 than for 8 & 10. Several of the other answers are equally good, although perhaps not as comprehensive, but include large graphics. In this case, the best, IMO, would have been to mark this question as a near duplicate of that answer. Yes, you can easily reverse "run as admin" settings, but the point is that it's very easy to forget that you're running as admin. Just emphasizing the need for informed choice.